# Xcode Rotation objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rotation

I am working on a Xcode project for rotation and I have it set to the following code but I have two buttons on it that when rotation occurs they disappear how can I fix it so it still shows when it rotates. This is Xcode for iOS app iOS 7. I tried doing this code and it rotates but the buttons get hidden when they rearrange.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}



-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}
```

Comment: ypu should look at autolayout : http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 1):

You need to set frame for both buttons when super view rotated. You need to reconsider their frames in x,y co-ordinates.